# Where can I find a detailed, up-to-date reference of HTML5 tags and attributes?

Tags: html, w3c

For example, I've been trying to find a reference page for the role attribute. I read that it is a standard attribute in HTML5. The best thing I could find was a w3.org release page for it (very lengthy and I couldn't find a table of some sorts illustrating the possible values for it).

Plus, I just realized that w3schools.com is a very bad reference, so now I'm using [w3c's html reference page](http://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements) as a substitute. Is there any other good references that may hold the key to the answer to the first part of my question?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of good references:

- http://www.html5code.com/
- http://html5boilerplate.com/
- http://html5demos.com/

Hope these help.  As the version is still evolving, the references are hit or miss.

Answer (score 1):

Also the [HTML5 editor's draft at w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

http://html5rocks.com 
   http://html5demos.com 
   http://html5doctor.com